# netbeans: English keyboard for code but other language keyboard for comments

Tags: netbeans, keyboard, comments

Is it possible to set that NetBeans automatically switches to other language keyboard, when I write comment?

For example: Now i must switch every time I write a comment because I use English keyboard for code but Czech keyboard for comment.